# Why doesn't my web site's port forwarding work?

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, website, lighttpd

I have made a website on my Raspberry Pi that works perfectly over the local network. It is running on lighttpd.

I have setup a DNS entry on [No-IP](https://NOIP.com) (`pumpkinprograms.ddns.net`) and I know that it works because I use it for other things. Finally, I port forwarded my router on port 80. Here is a pic (the Raspberry Pi’s IP address is 192.168.1.120). My router is an [ASUS RT-AC68U](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RTAC68U/).

[image: Router settings]

Why isn’t this working? I have setup a Minecraft server before so am baffled.

Comment: You have other services set up on the same IP: do they work? Are there any firewalls involved?

Comment: @AFH yes the FTP server does work and so do other things. I have the firewall setup but that is because otherwise port 80 and 443 go to the router homepage and another router page.

Comment: Have you tried mapping a different port, as in FTP and SSH (at least, I think that's what the line above is)?

Comment: @AFH Sorry I don't get what you mean. Do you mean put the server on port xxxx instead of 80?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: @AFH BTW I am testing out the server on an iPad with hotspot to test it and I get the error `network connection lost`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41425/discussion-between-afh-and-jonah-fleming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration looks correct, and the other services already set up are apparently working correctly.

After discussing the problem with the questioner, we tested setting the router to map the HTML port 80 on the web server to a different external port, and this works. It seems that the ISP is discouraging web servers by blocking port 80, and this is why the set-up is failing.

This gives a solution, to map port 80 to another port in the Dynamic DNS server and map this back to 80 in the router. This works round the ISP's restriction, but it may contravene the terms and conditions of service, making the service liable to cancellation.

The service conditions should be checked carefully and, if necessary, a different contract may need to be entered, possibly with a different ISP.